# Use CSS (or SCSS) to apply padding if element / tag has text or a sibling tag

Tags: css

I was wondering, say I have a button like so:

```
<button><i class="font-icon-class"></i></button>
```

would it be possible for me to add padding (or any other style) to the `.font-icon-class` should the button also contain text or another HTML tag? So if my button was like so:

```
<button><i class="font-icon-class"></i> Button Text </button>
```

or

```
<button><i class="font-icon-class"></i> <img src="..."></button>
```

I thought I could apply a `padding-right` using a CSS selector, something like

```
.font-icon-class + * { 
   padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work and I know I could use JavaScript but I was wondering if CSS could provide a solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem of course is that any selector you define will apply to the child\sibling\latter elements instead of the first element (which I'm aware you already know).  Apparently `:has` is coming at some point which may solve this one but it looks like you're stuck with a JS solution for now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the :only-child selector

```css
.font-icon-class:only-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
} 

.font-icon-class {
  width: 15px;
  background: lime;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

button {
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<button><i class="font-icon-class">test</i></button>
<button><i class="font-icon-class">test</i><span>HELLO</span></button>
```

Comment: What an inspired solution, love it

Comment: Brilliant solution... but I will use JS for now. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSav This is still a correct answer to your question, even though you aren't going to use it. If you mark it as such, others will be able to easier find it in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is short for Cascading Style Sheets, which means it adds the style as it goes down the code - not up. Therefore you can't (Yet? I believe I read somewhere you will be able to, in the future) add style to an element, if it has another element after.

A solution - if you have access to the HTML, would be to add a span around the element after the `.font-icon-class`, like so:

```
<button>
    <i class="font-icon-class"></i>
</button>

<button>
    <i class="font-icon-class"></i>
    <span>Button Text</span>
</button>

<button>
    <i class="font-icon-class"></i>
    <span><img src="..."></span>
</button>
```

And then your own CSS would work, but you could narrow it down so you don't target all elements after the `.font-icon-class`, change the padding to left, and display the span as inline-block:

```
.font-icon-class + span {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 5px; 
}
```

This would add a padding to the span-element inside the button, if it is after the `.font-icon-class`-element

Answer (score 0):

1. should the button also contain text or another HTML tag?

**there is no need of any HTML tag or text if you don't want.**

and from your question what I understood is, You can directly style the class like this,

and If want to add padding or any style just to next element in button, then you can do this,.

```
.font-icon-class + *{ any Style of your choice }
```

```css
.font-icon-class {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button><i class="font-icon-class"></i></button>
```